# Calling many Variables stored in outside file

Tags: php

The code I had help with the last couple weeks works great. The problem is it's creating way more needed includes and external files than I first thought and getting to be a challenge to keep track of.

I was told to use MySQL. That would be fine if the data was going to be used over again. The data is only used long enough to build the pages, print to pdf and then it's no longer needed and the files are deleted.

I have three templates that are used to create all the needed pages. Only the data is different but never the same to allow it to be saved beyond it's use.

The problem I started having is when 30+ pages are loaded into a single browser window so it can get processed to pdf, this is calling a few hundred includes and some are being missed. When each page is called by itself it all loads fine.

The other thing I can think of is to try and get the variables belonging to each page in it's own single file and have the page access that file. When I call the file with include "file.php"; it just prints everything to the screen and not where they are needed. That way each file would have 10 - 15 variables in it for each page This would eliminate over 400 external files down to 1+ images for each page.

Is putting them all in one separate file and then called possible?

I hope I explained this correctly.

Thanks in advance.

```
// What I would like in one file.
$item1 = "Data for Item one";
$photo1 = "img src string to image for item 1";

etc...

$item12 = "Data for Item 12";
$photo12 = "img src string to image for item 12";
```

This would then call the items in the proper location of the page.

```
echo "$item1";
echo "photo1";

etc...

echo "$item12";
echo "photo12";
```

Comment: Numbering them seems a clear indication they could be arrays....

Comment: I only numbered them that way to try and help keep track of what ones are for what pages since 30+ pages have 4 -  12 descriptions and 4 - 12 images each related to rental inspections. The 30+ pages are split over 16 sub directories or I would have serious clashes with the 24 files. Then when all 30+ pages are called on one page php doesn't do so well with the sub directories recursively is why I'm needing to re-do this whole process.

Comment: I don't fully follow, but it seems to me that you are wanting to use some strange design patterns. I do not know what you are doing, but it is possible you may be able to do it all client-side. Google: JavaScript PDF library.

Comment: In the file1.php: `return array(...)`, in file2.php: `$settings = require('file1.php`)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use a **MySQL database** to store information like that. (Settings, etc.)

But you can also use **arrays** for this which is probably more advisable.

---

## Solution with arrays

An array gives you the possibility to easily store and manage data of a similar type.
You create a new array like this:

```
$settings = array();
```

To store a value in it, you have several options:

- name it as an integer (0, 1, 2, 3 etc.)
- name it as a string ('item1', 'path2' etc.)

`$settings = array('path1', 'path2');`

This just stored `0 => 'path1'` and `1 => 'path1'`

To get the value of a key in an array:

```
echo $settings[0]; //or $settings{0}, outputs 'path1'
echo $settings[1]; //outputs 'path2'
```

Or you store it as a string:

```
$settings = array('picture1' => 'path1', 'picture2' => 'path2');
echo $settings['picture1']; //outputs 'path1'
```

Also, **multidimensional arrays** are possible:

```
$settings = array(
    'paths' => array(
        'picture1' => 'path1',
        'picture2' => 'path2'
    ),
    'language' => 'english'
);
```

You get a value of a multidimensional array like this:

```
//for every dimension a new [], outputs 'path1'
echo $settings['paths']['picture1'];
```

Then you can just *easily store* all your settings and `require_once 'settings.php';`.

If you want to learn more about arrays, go to the [php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php).

---

## Example:

**/php/settings.php**

```
$settings = array(
    'items' => array(
        'item1'  => 'Data for Item1',
        'item12' => 'Data for Item12',
    ),
    'photos' => array(
        'photo1'  => 'img src string to image for item 1',
        'photo12' => 'img src string to image for item 12',
    ),
);
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once '/php/settings.php';

echo $settings['items']['item1'];  //outputs 'Data for Item1'

//Or you can even use a foreach loop
foreach($settings['items'] as $key) {
    echo $key;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

That prints out:

> Data for Item1
>
> Data for Item12

Hope this helped.

Comment: What is the point of `.class.php`, I mean why namespace those files?

Comment: I do this everytime because I instantly know that there is only a class in that file. I just do this for better structure and easy understanding.

Comment: @Bluedayz, I considered MySQL but with the information being deleted after everything is done it was just a bunch of extra processes.

Comment: I highly recommend you to use multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @Bluedayz kind of looses me after a few lines, but I will see if I can figure how to put that into the top of the templates and make it work. I might have to go with just putting the variables in a php file and then append the template to it. Already have a combine working when I was going to split the template in 16 files and hard code the information and piece it together. That worked until a change had to be made to one piece of data.

Comment: I added an example to it. Better change your system now so it works fine than wait and then it is too hard to change everything because it is too much.